# Kernel slower on newer and "better" Nvidia GPUs

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, nvidia, raytracing

I created a real time ray tracer in OpenCL. This was developed on a GTX 580. I stopped working on it for a few years and recently resurrected it.  I expected that with newer and "better" Nvidia GPUs that it would run even faster. However, it still runs fastest on a GTX 580.

Here is a table of the times for a benchmark scene I use for three different computers and graphics cards

```
GPU          Kernel time    CPU                     OS             System Mem
GTX 580      11 ms          E5-1670                 Windows 7      32 GB
GTX Titan    15 ms          W5580 (two processors)  Windows 7      48 GB
GTX 980M     15 ms          i7-4710HQ (laptop)      Windows 10     16 GB
```

Each computer had Nvidia driver 361.43 installed on Jan. 10 2016 and the host code was compiled with Visual Studio 2013 64-bit release mode.

I also observe a faster frame rate on the GTX 580.

I used

```
time_end = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();
time_start = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
```

to get the kernel time. I don't use the double floating point extension (`//#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable`).

The kernel code is broken up into several kernel files which I assemble into one file which is several thousand lines of code.

Why is my kernel slower on newer and "better" hardware?

---

Here is the code where I create the context. It's not all going to make sense but it's probably better than nothing

```
void Contexts::init(string sourceCode) {
    run_time = -1;
    context = createCLContext(type, vendor);

    cl_uint uiNumSupportedFormats = 0;

    devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    int err = 0;
    try{
        //queues.push_back(cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[i], 0, &err));
        //queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[device], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
        queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[device], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE|CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, &err);
        //printf("\t\tDevice: %s\n", devices[device].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>().c_str());
    }
    catch (cl::Error er) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\n", er.what(), er.err());
    }


    //ndevices = devices.size();
    //if(ndevices>max_devices) ndevices = max_devices;

    program = buildProgramFromSource(context, sourceCode);

    try{
        kernel1 = cl::Kernel(program, "trace", &err);
        kernel2 = cl::Kernel(program, "transform_primitives", &err);
        kernel_postprocess = cl::Kernel(program, "post_process", &err);
    }
    catch (cl::Error er) {
        printf("ERROR: %s(%d)\n", er.what(), er.err());
    }
}

cl::Buffer Contexts::copy_buffer(int size, const void* ptr, int flags = CL_MEM_READ_ONLY) {
    cl::Buffer out;
    if(size>0) {
        out = cl::Buffer(context, flags| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  size, (void*)ptr);
    }
    else {
        //NULL pointers to kernel do not seem to work on INTEL so use this hack
        out = cl::Buffer(context, flags,  1, NULL);
    }
    return out;
}
void Contexts::copy_buffers() {
    //int cubemap_size = para->cubemap->sizeX * para->cubemap->sizeY * 6 * para->cubemap->ncubemap;

    //if(para->cubemap->sizeX== -1) cubemap_size = 0;
    int nobj = para->kernel1_parameters.nobj;
    int nprim = para->kernel1_parameters.nprim;
    int nmat= para->kernel1_parameters.nmat;
    int nlight = para->kernel1_parameters.nlight;
    int nnode = para->kernel1_parameters.nnode;
    int nmap = para->nmaps;

    int err = 0;

    int npixels = para->kernel1_parameters.height*para->kernel1_parameters.width;

    int exposure_samples = para->kernel1_parameters.exposure_samples;

    int mask_size = para->kernel1_parameters.mask_size;
    int nmask = (2*mask_size+1)*(2*mask_size+1);

    cl_objects_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(CSG_object)*nobj, para->objects);
    cl_node_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(Node)*nnode, para->nodes);
    cl_prim_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(Primitive)*nprim, para->prims, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE);
    cl_light_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(Light)*nlight, para->lights);
    cl_mat_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(Material)*nmat, para->mats);
    cubemap_info = copy_buffer(sizeof(Cubemap_info)*nmap, para->maps);
    cubemap_images = copy_buffer(sizeof(cl_uchar4)*para->envmap_npixels, para->envmap_images);
    cl_mask_mem = copy_buffer(sizeof(cl_float)*nmask, para->mask);

    cl_image_mem = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*npixels, NULL, &err);
    cl_results_mem = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_float4)*npixels, NULL, &err);
    cl_luminance = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float)*exposure_samples, NULL, &err);

    if(para->surfacecpy_sw) {
        cmPinnedBufOut1 = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY |CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*npixels, NULL, NULL);
        image = (int*)queue.enqueueMapBuffer(cmPinnedBufOut1, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*npixels, 0, NULL, NULL);
        //queue.enqueueUnmapMemObject(cmPinnedBufOut1, image);
        //int pageSize = 4096;
        //image = (int*) _aligned_malloc(sizeof(cl_uchar4)*npixels, pageSize);
        //CL_MEM_USE_PERSISTENT_MEM_AMD
    }
    cmPinnedBufOut2 = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY |CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float)*exposure_samples, NULL, NULL);
    luminance = (float*)queue.enqueueMapBuffer(cmPinnedBufOut2, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*exposure_samples, 0, NULL, NULL);

    queue.finish();
    //int kindex = 0;
    kernel1.setArg(0, cl_objects_mem);
    kernel1.setArg(1, cl_node_mem);
    kernel1.setArg(2, cl_prim_mem);
    kernel1.setArg(3, cl_mat_mem);
    kernel1.setArg(4, cl_light_mem);
    kernel1.setArg(5, cubemap_info);
    kernel1.setArg(6, cubemap_images);
    kernel1.setArg(7, cl_results_mem);

    kernel_postprocess.setArg(0, cl_results_mem);
    kernel_postprocess.setArg(1, cl_luminance);
    kernel_postprocess.setArg(2, cl_image_mem);
    kernel_postprocess.setArg(3, cl_mask_mem);

    kernel2.setArg(0, cl_prim_mem);

}

void Contexts::run() {
    int nprim = para->kernel2_parameters.nprim;
    cl_float speed = para->kernel2_parameters.speed;
    cl_float4 speed_obj = para->kernel2_parameters.speed_obj;
    cl_float16 cl_viewTransform;
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        cl_viewTransform.s[i] = para->viewTransform[i];
    //para->kernel1_parameters.offset = offset;
    //para->kernel1_parameters.offset2 = offset2;

    kernel1.setArg(8, cl_viewTransform);
    kernel1.setArg(9, para->kernel1_parameters);
    kernel1.setArg(10, offset);

    kernel_postprocess.setArg(4, para->kernel1_parameters);
    kernel_postprocess.setArg(5, offset);
    kernel_postprocess.setArg(6, offset2);

    //kernel1.setArg(11, offset2);
    cl::NDRange local_size = cl::NDRange(local_work_size);
    if(local_work_size == 0) {
        local_size = cl::NullRange;
    }
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel1, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(size),  local_size, NULL, &clevent);
    queue.finish();
    cl_ulong time_start, time_end;

    time_end = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();
    time_start = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();

    run_time = (float)(time_end - time_start);

    //post_process
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_postprocess, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(size),  local_size, NULL, &clevent);
    queue.finish();

    time_end = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();
    time_start = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();

    run_time += (float)(time_end - time_start);
    //printf("run time %f, run time2 %f\n", run_time, run_time2);

    //kernel2
    kernel2.setArg(1, speed);
    kernel2.setArg(2, speed_obj);
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel2, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(nprim), cl::NullRange, NULL, &clevent);
    queue.finish();

    time_end = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();
    time_start = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();

    run_time += (float)(time_end - time_start);

    if(para->getoutput_sw) {
        if(!para->surfacecpy_sw) {
            if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(para->surface)) {
                if(SDL_LockSurface(para->surface) < 0) return;
            }
            queue.enqueueReadBuffer(cl_image_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*size, (int*)para->surface->pixels + offset, NULL, &clevent);
            queue.finish();
            if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(para->surface))
                SDL_UnlockSurface(para->surface);
        }
        else {
            queue.enqueueReadBuffer(cl_image_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*size, (int*)image, NULL, &clevent);
            queue.finish();
        }
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(cl_luminance, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*size2, luminance, NULL, &clevent);
        queue.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting us to make blind guesses? The hardware has gotten more powerful, but we have no idea what your tracer looks like or how it operates.

Your benchmark times also look pretty small, it seems that in the ms range it'd be subject to random fluctuation too much to make accurate judgements on actual performance.

Comment: I realized that I may not have provided enough information to answer the question. But maybe this is a known problem with OpenCL and Nvidia? I may post my code soon but it's quite complex. The time discrepancies are not statistical fluctuation. I run at many frames per second (close to 90 FPS on the GTX 580) and I am quoting an average. The frame rate is noticeably different. The scenes can be dynamic (moving objects) but for the benchmark the scene is static.

Comment: "The GPU is better" that is a wild guess, everything might not been better. If the GPU A has 100 groups, and GPU B has 1000 groups, but same memory bus. Then a scattered read at the same time in the bus will colapse GPU B but not GPU A. It all boils down to the kernel you are using, and if it is generic enough to adapt and get extra performance of the new GPU.

Comment: @DarkZeros, I'm going to have to jump into this again and write some tests for each GPU. That's going to take some time which I don't have for a while.

Comment: GTX 580 has 16 smx (independent) units. GTX 980m has only 12. GTX580 shader frequency is 1544 MHz. When all rays do same thing, gtx980m would win. GTX 580 ---> more GB per second bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled out of order processing, I have faced a similar issue in Nvidia GPU's when doing basic image processing?

The code runs slower when you create your command queue as in order, but if your command queue created in OpenCL is out of order which is possible in the Nvidia GPU's then execution is exponentially fast.

Refer to the API

*cl_command_queue clCreateCommandQueue(  cl_context context,
    cl_device_id device,
    cl_command_queue_properties properties,
    cl_int *errcode_ret)*

https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html

The $cl_command_queue_properties should be set as $CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE

But make sure that you have no data dependencies in your kernel as in that case you cannot use this option.

Also, make sure you query the number of compute units and give your global work size and local work size accordingly.

E.g. My Nvidia GPU has 4 compute units, thus for best performance my global work size should be divisible by 4 and my local work size should be an integral multiple of 4

Comment: Thanks. I am using `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE`.

Comment: Check how you are utilizing global/local memory in kernels, if your kernel makes a lot of global memory accesses its still going to be slower. I really can't fathom why it is slower in a better gpu

Comment: You bring up a good point. I can post the code I use to create the context and run the kernels. That's not too long. I have not programmed OpenCL significantly in a few years.

Comment: Your answer did help me. I should have posted how I created the context for the kernels and got the output. I did that now. I should clean it up because a lot of it probably does not make sense.  As to the global size and local size I think I just set the global size to the number of pixels but I need to look into this.

Comment: Can you also just run a device query and post the specs of your opencl device, there are many device query code available online...

Answer (score 2):

(off the top of my head)

CUDA/PTX can be generated 32-bit or 64-bit.

OpenCL compiler generates by default:

- compute capability 2.0 -> 32 bit ptx
- compute capability 3.0 and higher -> 64 bit ptx

Your GPU's are:

- GTX 580 -> compute capability 2.0
- GTX Titan -> compute capability 3.5
- GTX 980M -> compute capability 5.2

You can output generated ptx to double check, without ptx knowledge it should be apparent whether ptx code is 32bit or 64bit and which compute capability that is.

You are probably experiencing higher register usage because of the switch into 64 bit ptx - have a look at CUDA occupancy calculator to check if slow down is expected. If that confirms then you will need to fine tune your kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide specific answers - there have been major changes to the streaming multiprocessor design between the GTX 580 and GTX 980. At the least, you'll probably need to find a new optimal local and global work group size.

What I would suggest is to use NVIDIA's profiling tools as they do still work for OpenCL. Take a look at this [post](http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl/) by @jrprice for detailed instructions. Once you have the profiling data logged, you can import it into the Visual Profiler and inspect your kernels for register & local memory usage and occupancy.